# Problems regarding Searle's Experiment

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

Recently I came across a problem on [**Searle's Experiment**](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=searle's+experiment) where we had to find the maximum possible error in *Young's modulus* calculation due to an error in the calculation of *extension of string*. Personally, I've never seen or done this experiment. My book says that the maximum error in *extension in string* calculation would be equal to the **least count** of the vernier callipers. I don't understand how is this possible. I've worked with a Vernier Callipers but I've never heard of anything like this before. Can someone brief the experiment for me and provide me with a satisfactory explanation?

Comment: Can you write the reference for "your book"?

Comment: Umm..actually it's a problem from previous IITJEE papers(a competitive exam held all over India), and it was a book consisting of all such solved previous papers.

Comment: If you can't cite it, it might be difficult to help you.